# Different P values for chi square test in Python and R

Tags: r, python-3.x, chi-squared

I am trying to do chi square test on two categories of biological data. I have a data frame like this:

```
         Brain, Cerebelum, Heart, Kidney,  liver,  testis
expected 3        66       1        44       34       88
observed 6        57       4        45       35       69

structure(list(Brain = c(3L, 6L), Cerebelum = c(66L, 57L), heart = c(1L, 
4L), kidney = 44:45, liver = 34:35, testis = c(88L, 69L)), .Names = c("Brain", 
"Cerebelum", "heart", "kidney", "liver", "testis"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("rand", 
"cns"))
```

I did the test using Python:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
chisquare(obs,f_exp=exp)
```

which gives result as:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=17.381684491978611, pvalue=0.0038300192430189722)
```

I tried to replicate the results using R, so I made the csv file, imported to R as dataframe and run the code as:

```
d<-read.csv(file)
chisq.test(d)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  d
X-squared = 4.9083, df = 5, p-value = 0.4272
```

why the chi squared value and P value is different in python and R?, As I calculated by hand using the simple (O-E)^2/E formula, the chi square value is equal to 17.38 as calculated by python but I can not figure out how R calculate the value of 4.90.

Comment: is `chisquare(obs, f_exp=exp)` doing the same thing as `chisq.tst(d)`? fwiw, `chisq.test(d)` in this case is treated as a two-d contingency table and `Pearson's chi-squared test is performed
     of the null hypothesis that the joint distribution of the cell
     counts in a 2-dimensional contingency table is the product of the
     row and column marginals.`

Comment: chisquare(obs,f_exp=exp) in python is simply running the (Observed-Expected)^2/Expected formula  that is different from what you described as R is doing. So which p value is correct here the one from R or from Python?

Comment: gotcha. i put an answer for that. there's probably some quick way to turn E/O into an equivalent contingency table but I don't know it. also the two question are kinda different. possibly you should edit this one and ask a second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer your first question.

`chisq.test`, when you give it a matrix with `> 2` rows and columns, treats it as two-dimensional contingency table and tests for independence between observations along the rows and columns. [Here's an example](http://people.reed.edu/~jones/141/chisq.html) and [another one](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chisq.htm).

`scipy.stats.chisq` on the other hand just does the `X = sum( (O_i-E_i)^2 / E_i)` familiar from the [definition of the test stat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic).

So how to square the circle? First, pass `R` the observed values, then define the expected probabilities in argument `p`. Second, you also need to stop R from doing a default continuity correction.

```
e <- d[1, ]
o <- d[2, ]
chisq.test(o, p = e / sum(e), correct = FALSE)
```

voila

```
Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  o
X-squared = 17.139, df = 5, p-value = 0.004243
```

**PS** Tricky question for SO, possibly better for crossvalidated?
Note that R's default correction may be a good thing vs `scipy`. Whether that is true is definitely for crossvalidated.

**PPS**
The help in `?chisq.test` is a litttttttle hard to parse, but I think this is all in there somewhere ;)

```
 If ‘x’ is a matrix with one row or column, or if ‘x’ is a vector
 and ‘y’ is not given, then a _goodness-of-fit test_ is performed
 (‘x’ is treated as a one-dimensional contingency table).  The
 entries of ‘x’ must be non-negative integers.  In this case, the
 hypothesis tested is whether the population probabilities equal
 those in ‘p’, or are all equal if ‘p’ is not given.

 If ‘x’ is a matrix with at least two rows and columns, it is taken
 as a two-dimensional contingency table: the entries of ‘x’ must be
 non-negative integers.  Otherwise, ‘x’ and ‘y’ must be vectors or
 factors of the same length; cases with missing values are removed,
 the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is
 computed from these.  Then Pearson's chi-squared test is performed
 of the null hypothesis that the joint distribution of the cell
 counts in a 2-dimensional contingency table is the product of the
 row and column marginals.
```

and

```
 correct: a logical indicating whether to apply continuity correction
          when computing the test statistic for 2 by 2 tables: one half
          is subtracted from all |O - E| differences; however, the
          correction will not be bigger than the differences
          themselves.  No correction is done if ‘simulate.p.value =
          TRUE’.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but why I get the error "Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'" when trying to run your R code?!

Comment: not sure. maybe your `d` wasn't the same type as mine? or its names messed things up? provide the output of `dput(d)` for your variable `d` (edit the question to add it, as it's good practice)